# Magento Low Stock Report

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 and have noticed that my Low Stock report is always blank. Is there anything specific I need to do to have this report display my inventory stock levels? I have Magento set to manage my inventory and I have about 100 products in the store now. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In magento admin panel Go to **System->Configuration->Inventoty->Product Stock Options** and set **Notify for Quantity Below** to the required value.Now when you generate low stock report 
all the products having the quantity below **Notify for Quantity Below** value wil be dispalyed.